# PHP framework for SPAs?

Tags: php, frameworks, single-page-application

There are a few micro-frameworks for PHP like Slim, Silex... but none of them are focused on Single Page Applications. There is some kind of framework focused on SPAs? That only handle DB requests ant let client-side frameworks like Angular and Backbone do the rendering part?

---

Ok. So, my research guides me to this: https://github.com/leocavalcante/spa
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the micro-frameworks do not impose a particular templating engine for rendering. You could easily role your own that just outputs json data that was pulled from a DB.

Most of the popular frameworks are based around a [routing architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework#URL_mapping) called "url dispatch". Basically a URL maps to a route/controller, with options for regular expressions for wild carding.

A far less common method is referred to as "traversal" or "component" routing. Zope is probably the most popular of this style. That is designed around loading objects, like from a database. Although Zope is written in Python.

I made an attempt at a component "traversal" based framework called [Basecoat](https://github.com/shutterstock/basecoat), which is open sourced. Each "directory" in the URL can be treated as a module (i.e. /module1/module2/module3), which lends itself to mapping to modules on a page. It's 4 files: bootstrap, router, db, content. It may fit what your are looking to do.